# Обход active record

Tags: yii2, yii

Есть модель со списком ползователей:

```
$model = users::model()->findAll();
```

Мне нужно из этого списка получить только фамилии и составить из них строку этих фамилий через запятую. Я конечно мог бы с помощью `php foreach` обойти весь этот список. Но меня интересует нет существует ли более удобного способа получения полей списка с помощью самой **activerecord**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Yii2 можно так:

```
join(', ', User::find()->select('last_name')->column());
```

В первом Yii, самым простым будет обход списка в цикле.